# How can I install Windows 11 offline?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-11, windows-installation, windows-11-v22h2

While on previous Windows versions I just could unplug the network cable during installation to do an offline installation with a local account, Windows 11 does not let me proceed without an internet connection.

If an internet connection is available, I cannot choose to install it with a local account: I have to either use a MS account or a security token that is connected to a MS account.

Is there any way in Windows 11 to install it offline (with a local account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new way to enforce an offline installation in Windows 11:

1. As soon as the out-of-box experience (OOBE) installation screen pops up (e. g. where you have to select a country/region), press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> on your keyboard to bring up a command line.
2. Type in `OOBE\BYPASSNRO` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (yes, no spaces)

Your computer will reboot and OOBE will start again, but this time without the need to be online: On the screen *Let's connect you to a network* you now have the additional button *I don't have internet*, that was missing previously.